# JQUery UI element customization using addClass

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am extending JQuery UI slider by specifying a custom style for its handle.

The code is as follows:

JavaScript:

```
var slider = $("#container").slider();
var handle = $(".ui-slider-handle", slider);
```

Then I'm doing

```
handle.css("backgroundColor","yellow");
```

which works.

But when I create a class like:

```
.yellow
{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

and use

```
  handle.addClass("yellow"); // works!
```

it doesn't pick it up. Let me clarify one thing - the CSS location is valid and my custom CSS gets applied **after** the JQuery CSS, if I to override JQuery original styles in my custom CSS by writing:

```
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle 
{ 
   background-color: yellow;    
}
```

it works again. it's just addClass what just doesn't seem to honored. Could anyone advice on how to I get it working with addClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem with [css specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) meaning that your class `.yellow` has less specificity that `.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle`

One solution is to add specificity to yellow so it doesn't get override like

```
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle.yellow {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: how do I do it with jQuery please? I've a few sliders, which get their classes assigned dynamically, so jQuery is the only way to go for me.

Comment: Your jQuery code is correct, you just have to create the css class correctly. If you only want to use jQuery, you'll have to use the line you wrote `handle.css("backgroundColor","yellow");`